# How to calculate similarity between two signature images

Tags: python, opencv

I have signature images like this one:
[image]

[image]

Both of these signatures are similar and I need to print if they are similar or not.
I have tried SSIM, MSE, SIFT and Cosine similarity.
SSIM gives almost more than 0.7 index for both similar and dissimilar images.
MSE gives a very large distance once these are cleaned and compared
SIFT gave 66 features matches
And cosine similarity gave 0.08
Here is the code that helps clean the images

```
image = cv2.imread('test2.png')
image = cv2.resize(image, (680, 460))
image = cv2.detailEnhance(image)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (1,1), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Filter using contour area and remove small noise
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 5500:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)


        # Morph close and invert image
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,1))
close = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)
cv2.imshow('thresh', close) ###for showing 
cv2.waitKey()
kernel = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)
# sign2 = cv2.dilate(close,kernel,iterations = 1)
sign2= close

# cv2.imshow('thresh', sign2) ###for showing 
# cv2.waitKey()
```

I clean both images and then compare.

Is there any other way to compare them. All I want is if they are similar then just say yes :p

Comment: This is not trivial at all. There are [papers](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1993/file/288cc0ff022877bd3df94bc9360b9c5d-Paper.pdf) dedicated to solving this problem.

Comment: @eldesgraciado this paper checks if it is genuine or forged. I only need to check if they look similar or not

Comment: so this is sordt of image similiarity problem